# How to implement the creation of folders structure for uploaded files on php

Tags: php, file-upload, uploading

Say I want my uploaded files to be stored in a structure of subdirectories as shown below:

```
    /uploads/0/0/kitten.jpg;
    /uploads/0/1/kitten1.jpg;
    /uploads/1/10/pic.jpg;
```

So that each subfolder can contain 999 files at max i.e. when /uploads/0/ reaches its limit, the folder /uploads/1/ is created automaticaly and next file goes there. Each folder also can contain 999 subfolders.

**The question is - How do I do that?** My main concern is how to determine where to put the newly uploaded file. Could you describe the algorithm? I cannot think of anything better than performing these steps each time:

1. Looking for the latest created folder in /uploads/ and if it's empty -  creating one, like so:

   ```
   $contents = $scandir('/uploads');
       $dirs = array();
       foreach ($contents as $path) {
           if (is_dir($path)) {
             $dirs[] = $path;
           }
       }
       if (empty($dirs)) {
            //create new dir and save file there subsequently
            $saveTo = $parentDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "1" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "1";
            mkdir($saveTo, 0777, true);
       } else {
           $last = array_pop($dirs);
       }
   ```
2. We do basically the same for this subfolder and so on(and I guess I may want to use recursion here somehow). Am I moving in right direction here or maybe I am overcomplicating things? Is there a better way to do this? Anything, please. I am only beginner in php and coding.

Comment: Would you mind using date, like 2013/4/5, as subfolder?

Comment: And how to separate those files which were uploaded at the same day? There may be thousands of them. I need to store each one in the separate folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to keep a running total of all uploads, (atomically) increasing it for each upload.

Then the directory can be created like so:

```
$dir = sprintf('/uploads/%d/%d', floor($total / 1000), $total % 1000);
if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
}
```

Comment: That looks like really clever and elegant solution, I give you that, sir, but where do you I store the total number of all uploads?

Comment: @dKab There are a few options; a database is one way, or a simple file that's protected with advisory locking, see [`flock()`](http://php.net/flock).